# TextBlock not Wrapping Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have a TextBlock that is not wrapping and thinks it has an infinite width. I have tried to bind it to the actualWidth of the Grid and/or UserControl, but both widths come as more than 8000. I have tried disabling the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility in the parent view, but that does not work either. I have also read all question in SO that are related to mine and none of the suggestions seems to work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Civica.UI.CurrentUserMenu.Views.ClassName"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SeparatorBrush" Color="#66848484" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Viewer" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="UserControl">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SeparatorBrush}" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Text" Margin="0" FontWeight="Black" />
                </Border>

                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding TextProperty}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

EDIT:

This is the code for the parent view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Civica.UI.Ribbon.Views.ViewName"

             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewMOdelName}"
             d:DesignHeight="120"
             d:DesignWidth="600"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">    
        <telerik:RadRibbonView x:Name="RadRibbon"
                               Title="Title"
                               ApplicationButtonContent="Content"
                               ApplicationMenu="{Binding PropertyName}"
                               ApplicationName="{Binding PropertyName}"
                               MinimizeButtonVisibility="Visible"
                               SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
       </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It is the RadRibbonView that contains the first view.

Comment: Well, it's inside Grid and ScrollViewer, it will get all the width it wants. You need to restrict the size, set MaxWidth on it, for example.

Comment: If I hard code the maxWidth, it wraps, but I want it to resize dynamically with the screen.

Comment: I guess it depends on where your UserControl is located. I copied your code and it wraps correctly.

Comment: This is what I thought as well and tried hardcoding the MaxWidth of the parent UserControl and it did make the screen smaller, but my TextBlock still didn't wrap.

Comment: Is that your whole layout shown there? You might show more if you can, there's got to be a culprit not being seen.

Comment: The original code is everything I have in the actual View, however I have added the code for the parent View.

Comment: Nah, I mean for example you have a column/row of 1 defined on that ScrollViewer, so made me think there may be more to it since the column/row or the parent Grid of it itself for that matter wouldn't be necessary otherwise.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I must have tried something and the forgotten to delete them.

Comment: I'm still not understanding how on earth you're getting a >8000 width on your parents though. Like there has to be something else going on. What if you bind to `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` do you get the same thing? Just having your horizontal disabled should provide the boundary required to invoke your wrapping.

Comment: Binding the width of the inner Grid to the ViewportWidth didn't make a difference. According to the binding the ViewportWidth is 8505, which I assume is the length of the text I want to display.

Comment: Yea this is such a one-off scenario it has to be something specific to your setup/layout. There's nothing fancy going on with the string you're putting in there to preserve white space or anything right? There just has to be something missing here because these controls just don't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a style that was being applied by the parent view and specifically a Telerik object. The solution was to find that style, decompile it and copy is to one of our files and change a scrollviewer to a border.